# How to get the names of an input text fields in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the `name` of an input text field in my html tag.
How do we achieve this with class name or any specific way to get the name of each input text fields?
Below javascript gives only the name of the first input text field. How can I achieve this?

```html
<div id="firstlevelforthe-page1">
  <div class="first-one-in level">
      <li id= "item_1G2FogWpQkyYzgjWNdfghj" class="first one class-nextlevel-one">  
         <div>
         <div class="somelable-here1">Label 1</div>
         <input type="text" name="dRFTeds23HJKLhgd45" class="textquestion singleline"><br><br>                   
         </div>
        
      </li>
      
      <li id= "item_1G2FogWpQkyYzgjWNa4j9w" class="first one class-nextlevel-second">  
         <div>
         <div class="somelable-here2">Label 2</div>         
         <input type="text" name="uiopGHJFG6854GFD" class="textquestion multiline"><br><br>               
         </div>        
      </li>
      
      <li id= "item_1G2FogWpQkyY234" class="first one class-nextlevel-third">  
         <div>
         <div class="somelable-here2">Label 3</div>         
          <input type="text" name="asdfTYHJK345VB" class="textquestion email"><br><br>               
         </div>        
      </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Java script code

```
var nameArr = new Array();
 nameArr = $('input[type="text"]').attr('name');
 console.log(nameArr);
 document.getElementById('printhere').innerHTML= nameArr;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to loop over the selected elements.

```js
$('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
  console.log(this.name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><div id="firstlevelforthe-page1">  <div class="first-one-in level">      <li id= "item_1G2FogWpQkyYzgjWNdfghj" class="first one class-nextlevel-one">           <div>         <div class="somelable-here1">Label 1</div>         <input type="text" name="dRFTeds23HJKLhgd45" class="textquestion singleline"><br><br>                            </div>              </li>            <li id= "item_1G2FogWpQkyYzgjWNa4j9w" class="first one class-nextlevel-second">           <div>         <div class="somelable-here2">Label 2</div>                  <input type="text" name="uiopGHJFG6854GFD" class="textquestion multiline"><br><br>                        </div>              </li>            <li id= "item_1G2FogWpQkyY234" class="first one class-nextlevel-third">           <div>         <div class="somelable-here2">Label 3</div>                   <input type="text" name="asdfTYHJK345VB" class="textquestion email"><br><br>                        </div>              </li>  </div></div>
```

Or you can use the function `$.toArray()`

```js
var array = $('input[type="text"]').toArray();

array.forEach(function(e) {
  console.log(e.name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><div id="firstlevelforthe-page1">  <div class="first-one-in level">      <li id= "item_1G2FogWpQkyYzgjWNdfghj" class="first one class-nextlevel-one">           <div>         <div class="somelable-here1">Label 1</div>         <input type="text" name="dRFTeds23HJKLhgd45" class="textquestion singleline"><br><br>                            </div>              </li>            <li id= "item_1G2FogWpQkyYzgjWNa4j9w" class="first one class-nextlevel-second">           <div>         <div class="somelable-here2">Label 2</div>                  <input type="text" name="uiopGHJFG6854GFD" class="textquestion multiline"><br><br>                        </div>              </li>            <li id= "item_1G2FogWpQkyY234" class="first one class-nextlevel-third">           <div>         <div class="somelable-here2">Label 3</div>                   <input type="text" name="asdfTYHJK345VB" class="textquestion email"><br><br>                        </div>              </li>  </div></div>
```

Using Arrow functions

```js
var array = $('input[type="text"]').toArray().map(({name}) => name);
console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><div id="firstlevelforthe-page1">  <div class="first-one-in level">      <li id= "item_1G2FogWpQkyYzgjWNdfghj" class="first one class-nextlevel-one">           <div>         <div class="somelable-here1">Label 1</div>         <input type="text" name="dRFTeds23HJKLhgd45" class="textquestion singleline"><br><br>                            </div>              </li>            <li id= "item_1G2FogWpQkyYzgjWNa4j9w" class="first one class-nextlevel-second">           <div>         <div class="somelable-here2">Label 2</div>                  <input type="text" name="uiopGHJFG6854GFD" class="textquestion multiline"><br><br>                        </div>              </li>            <li id= "item_1G2FogWpQkyY234" class="first one class-nextlevel-third">           <div>         <div class="somelable-here2">Label 3</div>                   <input type="text" name="asdfTYHJK345VB" class="textquestion email"><br><br>                        </div>              </li>  </div></div>
```

Comment: Any other way, preferably a single line code other than each function.

Comment: @soccerway using arrow functions.  See the update answer!

Answer (score 0):

you have to use loop to iterate each element of DOMlist:

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('name'))
})
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, which does not even require JQuery:

```
var inputNames = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('input')).map(node => node.name);
```

This uses the web API to get an HTMLCollection containing all the